# A question concerned to the participles

Tags: phrases, adjectives, participles, present-participles, participial-phrases

*The traveller, being weary, sat by the woodside to rest.*

My book says the present participle *being weary* (passive) is used absolutely in the sentence with the noun *The traveller*. But it's separated by a comma and the sentence makes sense without the participle. I think the the book is wrong and it's a particle phrase or adjective phrase and it's not used absolutely with the noun *the traveller*. The noun *the traveller* is attached to the independent clause and *being weary* is a participle or adjective phrase separated by the commas. Am I wrong?

Comment: In this usage of the term 'absolute', the implication is that though there is a referent, the descriptor is not linked by being in a prenominal (a _weary_ traveller), postnominal (the people _concerned_) or predicative (the traveller is _weary_) position. A debated usage.

Comment: You probably mean 'participle phrase'; 'participial clause' is the preferred terminology and analysis nowadays. This is a non-defining participial clause, 'non-defining' as it does not identify a particular traveller. It corresponds to the non-defining relative clause [,] who was weary[,].

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you wrote. Can you please explain in simple terms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Examples of absolute phrases with adverbs instead of participles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452839/examples-of-absolute-phrases-with-adverbs-instead-of-participles) (Billy's example 'Dressed to the nines, she walked gracefully into the room.')

Comment: "Being weary" is a non-finite clause, but it has no subject so it can't be an absolute. It's actually a depictive adjunct, predicative in that it relates to a predicand, here "the traveller".